# Mongoose / MongoDB schemas for blog posts and authors

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm programming a model for a blog with authors and posts. I was following this doc: **[Mongoose Query Population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)**

My concern is that the createPost function is inefficient. 
Another option is to nest the posts in the Author, but how I will get all posts? Should I use MySQL? Am I doing it right? (Take a look at the functions as well)

Some more details:

**[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/aD7kknvK)**

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose");
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let PostSchema = Schema({
    title: {type: String},
    body: {type: String},
    date: {type: Date},
    tags:[{type: String}],
    _author: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'author'}
});

let AuthorSchema = Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    photo: {type: String},
    bio: {type: String},
    username: {type: String, index: true},
    posts:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'post'}],
    password: {type: String}
});

let Author = mongoose.model('author', AuthorSchema);
let Post = mongoose.model('post', PostSchema);

module.exports = Author;
module.exports = Post;

module.exports.createAuthor = (newAuthor, callback)=>{
    newAuthor.save(callback)
};

module.exports.createPost = (username, newPost, callback)=>{
        Author.findOne({username:username}).then((author)=>{
            newPost._author = author._id
            author.posts.push(newPost);
            newPost.save().then(err, auth)=>{
                author.save(callback);
            };
        },(err)=>{
            if(err)
            throw err;
        });
};

module.exports.getAuthorByPostTitle = (postTitle, callback)=>{
        Post.findOne({title:postTitle}).populate('_author').exec((err, post)=>{
            if(err)
                throw err;
            else
                return post._author;
        });
};

module.exports.getPostsByAuthorId = (authorId, callback)=>{
        Post.find({_author:authorId}).exec((err, posts)=>{
            if(err)
                throw err;
            else
                return posts;
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `forEach` function like this

```
const allPosts = [];

Author.find({}, function(err, users) {
    if (err) throw err;

    users.forEach(function(user) {
        const a = user.posts;
        a.forEach(us => allPosts.push(us));
    });
});
```

Now the `allPosts` array will have all the posts.

Comment: It would have been better to edit your first answer, rather than posting a new. You can see the `[edit]` and `[delete]` links below the text of your posts.

Comment: Ok, that would solve the problem of querying all posts

Comment: What do you think about the createPost function?